# Groovy range stops working after two characters?

Tags: groovy

I'm working with groovy version 2.4.10 and stumbled upon a weird behaviour with ranges:

```
1..50      --> [1,2,3,4....,50] //ok, as expexted
'a'..'z'   --> [a,b,...,z] 
'a1'..'a5' --> [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]

'a1'..'a15' --> [a1]   //These are wrong
'a1'..'a35' --> [a1, a2, a3]
```

So it seems that the range stops working after 2 characters. Is this expected behavior or a bug in iterator or something? The documentation says that

> Ranges can be used for any Java object which implements java.lang.Comparable for comparison and also have methods next() and previous() to return the next / previous item in the range. For example, you can create a range of String elements.

Since `'a35'.previous()`, `'a35'.next()` work as expected, shouldn't the range as well?

Comment: Did you also check what `'a1'.next()` returns? And how the comparison `'a2' < 'a15'` works?

Comment: @UnholySheep they return a2 and false. The second one is wrong, but for example `'a200' < 'a35'` returns true, so it's the same reason for this case.

Comment: The second one isn't wrong, that is how string comparison works. it compares character by character and `2` is lexical higher than `1`. If you want to create a range of strings from 'a10' to 'a15' then your range needs to be `'a10'..'a15'` the compiler cannot magically infer that for you

Comment: So what you're saying is that because of the compiler's way of doing string comparison, it doesn't work, I see, thank you. However, if in the case of `'a1'..'a35'` the comparison shows that a1 < a35 is true, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to just call next() till a35... This is a implementation detail so I wouldn't know.

Comment: You are expecting the compiler to "know" that it is supposed to add more characters to a string, but how is it supposed to figure out whether it should go from 'a1' to 'a11'? Why not 'a101' or 'a1001'? There'd be an endless amount of possibilities, so it instead does the most obvious thing and just increments the last character

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it, thanks.